# How can I launch a named Linux screen which executes a script at launch automatically?

Tags: linux, bash, script

How can I launch a named Linux screen which executes a script at launch automatically?

So I want to use screen with these 2 conditions.

1. The screen session should be named
2. The screen session should be able to launch a script automatically inside of it. Let's say script.sh for example. So when the command I'm looking for is executed a screen session launches and the script.sh automatically launches inside the screen session.

Anyone? Please remember both conditions need to be fulfilled.

Comment: Are you referring to the UNIX screen command ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want an interactive screen :

```
screen -S myScreen /bin/bash --init-file ./screen_cmd.sh
```

If your script is going to stay alive (e.g. a server) :

```
screen -S myScreen /bin/bash ./screen_cmd.sh
```

You can reattach to the screen with

```
screen -r myScreen
```

Hope this helps.